# Issue of template also getting copied along with the newly generated mail using the VBA script

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2010

I am trying to read values from an excel and create outlook mail from a template with different values present in each of the excel . But during the creation of the mail , the mail with values is getting generated and also the template is also copied in every mail . I am not able to find the root cause for it.

```
Sub SendMail()
Dim sendTo As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strMail As String
Dim table As Range
Dim row As Range


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set table = Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
For Each row In table.Rows
    strMail = row.Cells(x, y).Value ' Email address in A1 cell
    strSubject = "Good morning"
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\temp.oft")
    'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(OutApp)

        With OutMail
            .To = strMail
            .Subject = strSubject
            .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "abc", strme) ' These strings are read from excel
            .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "myname", stryou)
            .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "hi", strQuant)
            .Display 'Show mail message.
        End With
Next row
' *** TIDY UP ***
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking and what the problem is. Is it that all emails have the same values of strme, stryou, and strQuant? Well, you never set these variables to values specific to a particular row.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, just to let you know, I've removed the [office-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-automation) tag because this question is about VBA (macros) and not about an external software like the tag definition indicates.

Comment: Outlook is automated from an external application which is Excel in that case.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - it's true, but Excel is an MS Office product and the definition says "not an MS Office product".

Comment: An external application (Outlook) is automated from Excel (which is a MS product in the description).

Comment: I’ve removed the `office-automation` tag because the question actually does not seem to fit the current `office-automation` tag guidance. If the intention is for a question like this one to be in scope for the `office-automation` tag, then the tag guidance there should be updated to more clearly allow it. But as currently worded, it seems like a reasonable person reading that tag guidance would conclude it considers this question to be out of scope for the tag.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are setting non-existing values for the placeholders of the item created from the template:

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "abc", strme) ' These strings are read from excel
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "myname", stryou)
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "hi", strQuant)
```

Most probably you need to read corresponding values from the Excel file.